# MATLAB dimensions of logical array

Tags: matlab, size

I have a problem in MATLAB. I have a NxM logical array called `L` but if I do `dim(L)` I get:

```
Undefined function or method 'dim' for input arguments of type 'logical'
```

`size` doesn't work either. `length` works but gives me only the number of columns and not the rows.
The weird thing is that in the Matlab workspace it is correctly shown as an NxM logical array.

Does anyone know how I can get the amount of rows and columns of a logical array?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both the number of rows and colums, `size` is your best choice:

```
[nRows,nCols] = size(L)
```

If this fails, use `clear size` first, since you may accidentially have a variable of the same name in your workspace.

Comment: Oh wow now I feel stupid. Indeed I had defined a variable called size :S
Thanks a looot for the tip.
Should I delete the post maybe?

But seriously, why would MATLAB allow me to define a variable with a name of a built in function. At least a warning would be nice!

Comment: @Stefan: Matlab gives you a lot of freedom, including the freedom to shoot yourself in the foot. If you feel to embarrassed, you can delete your post, of course, otherwise, please accept my answer :)

Comment: @Stefan, I can't see any reason to delete this post. It might be helpful to many more people. I remember that I once defined a "try.m" script and tried to run it. I think it took me 2 hours to understand what is wrong.